# addListener click is not showing add marker

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I've created below code, however i'm trying to make it possible for the user to add a marker, i've tried to use a addListener with a click event. When i try to click on the map nothing happens, what am i doing wrong?

```
<head>
<style>
html, body {
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right:  0px;
  margin-bottom:  0px;
  margin-top:  0px;
}
#mapContainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right:  0px;
  margin-bottom:  0px;
  margin-top:  0px;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
}

.gm-style-mtc {
  display: none;
}

.gmnoprint {
  display: none;
}

</style>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="mapContainer">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>


  <script>
  var mapCanvas;
  function initialize() {

    var myOptions = {
      center: {lat: 40.740, lng: -74.18},
      zoom : 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    mapCanvas = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"), myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: mapCanvas.getCenter(),
     map: mapCanvas

    });
    var imageBounds = {
      north: 40.773941,
      south: 40.712216,
      east: -74.12544,
      west: -74.22655
    };
    historicalOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
    'https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mgx2.jpg',
    imageBounds);
    historicalOverlay.setMap(mapCanvas);


    // This event listener calls addMarker() when the map is clicked.
      google.maps.event.addListener(mapCanvas, 'click', function(e) {
        placeMarker(e.latLng, mapCanvas);
      });


    //Changes zoom levels when the projection is available.
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(mapCanvas, "projection_changed", function(){
      mapCanvas.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID);  //Changes the MapTypeId in short time.
      setZoomLimit(mapCanvas, google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
      setZoomLimit(mapCanvas, google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID);
      setZoomLimit(mapCanvas, google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE);
      setZoomLimit(mapCanvas, google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
      mapCanvas.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);  //Sets the MapTypeId to original.
    });
  }

  function placeMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: mapCanvas
    });

    map.setCenter(location);
  }

  function setZoomLimit(map, mapTypeId){
    //Gets MapTypeRegistry
    var mapTypeRegistry = mapCanvas.mapTypes;

    //Gets the specified MapType
    var mapType = mapTypeRegistry.get(mapTypeId);
    //Sets limits to MapType
    mapType.maxZoom = 15;  //It doesn't work with SATELLITE and HYBRID maptypes.
    mapType.minZoom = 15;
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
    </script>
    <body>
```

Comment: Any errors reported in your console?

Comment: Also below, if your map is `mapCanvas`, why do you use `map.setCenter(location)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [GroundOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#GroundOverlay) is capturing the click event.

You have two options:

1. set the `clickable` option to false

```
historicalOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
  'https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mgx2.jpg',imageBounds,{clickable: false});
historicalOverlay.setMap(mapCanvas);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/7093qbbm/)

2. add a listener to the overlay

```
google.maps.event.addListener(historicalOverlay, 'click', function(e) {
  placeMarker(e.latLng, mapCanvas);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/7093qbbm/1/)

Comment: but shouldnt there pop something up so you can write a labe aswell?

Comment: There will only be an InfoWindow if your code creates one.  Currently the code inside your `placeMarker` function doesn't create one (if that is what you are asking).

Answer (score 0):

The overlay is blocking the default map. Add the listener to the overlay.

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(historicalOverlay, 'click', function(e) {
    placeMarker(e.latLng, mapCanvas);
  });
```

Trying to show a Demo below:

```js
 var mapCanvas;

 function initialize() {

   var myOptions = {
     center: {
       lat: 40.740,
       lng: -74.18
     },
     zoom: 15,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };
   mapCanvas = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"), myOptions);

   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: mapCanvas.getCenter(),
     map: mapCanvas

   });
   var imageBounds = {
     north: 40.773941,
     south: 40.712216,
     east: -74.12544,
     west: -74.22655
   };
   historicalOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
     'https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mgx2.jpg',
     imageBounds);
   historicalOverlay.setMap(mapCanvas);


   // This event listener calls addMarker() when the map is clicked.
   google.maps.event.addListener(historicalOverlay, 'click', function(e) {
     console.log("clicked'");
     placeMarker(e.latLng, mapCanvas);
   });


   //Changes zoom levels when the projection is available.
   google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(mapCanvas, "projection_changed", function() {
     mapCanvas.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID); //Changes the MapTypeId in short time.
     setZoomLimit(mapCanvas, google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
     setZoomLimit(mapCanvas, google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID);
     setZoomLimit(mapCanvas, google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE);
     setZoomLimit(mapCanvas, google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
     mapCanvas.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP); //Sets the MapTypeId to original.
   });
 }

 function placeMarker(location) {
   console.log("place a marker");
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: location,
     map: mapCanvas
   });

   map.setCenter(location);
 }

 function setZoomLimit(map, mapTypeId) {
   //Gets MapTypeRegistry
   var mapTypeRegistry = mapCanvas.mapTypes;

   //Gets the specified MapType
   var mapType = mapTypeRegistry.get(mapTypeId);
   //Sets limits to MapType
   mapType.maxZoom = 15; //It doesn't work with SATELLITE and HYBRID maptypes.
   mapType.minZoom = 15;
 }

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
#mapContainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
.gm-style-mtc {
  display: none;
}
.gmnoprint {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

  <div id="mapContainer">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

And your map variable name is mapCanvas not map

```
function placeMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: mapCanvas
    });

    **mapCanvas**.setCenter(location);
}
```

And you can take free api key. Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=**AIza14746817467416y01Dipl7TZVXfDmUCyY**&sensor=true&language=tr"></script>
```